# Was S.P.E.W. successful?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

After the last Harry Potter book, was S.P.E.W. (the Society for the Promotion of Elfish Welfare) successful?

I know that Hermione said that she wanted to "take S.P.E.W. further" when talking about careers in OotP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Further to Richard's answer, it should be noted that:

> Katieleigh: Does hermione still continue to do work with spew and is life any better for house elves!
> J.K. Rowling: Hermione began her post-Hogwarts career at the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures where she was instrumental in greatly improving life for house-elves and their ilk. She then moved (despite her jibe to Scrimgeour) to the Dept. of Magical Law Enforcement

[J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat, Bloomsbury.com](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)

Her position within the Department for Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures provided an excellent platform for Hermione - founder and foremost proponent of SPEW - to further the cause of House Elves.

Comment: Ooh. How did I miss that?

Comment: @Richard In addition - and this is speculative on my part - we might assume that Hermione was satisfied with what she achieved for Elvish welfare, as she later moved to the Department of Magical Law Enforcement. Although Hermione's opinion is perhaps not the most objective measure of how effectively SPEW met its goals.

Comment: I switched your quote to the exact form found in the transcript on accio-quote. If you don't like it, then rollback.

Comment: @ibid - Even better.

Comment: I love how JKR gets to edit her omissions, years after the fact. Ha

Comment: @ibid no worries, looks fine. Thanks.

Comment: @user001 - Tolkien rewrote the entire Gollum chapter of the Hobbit *thirteen* years after it was published. What JKR did was nothing.

Comment: @ibid Tolkien was always changing agreed but usually fixing errors or changing the overall narrative, to improve the story and at his own behest (which then became the revised editions for popular sale). JKR's latter books were overly bloated and needed major editing (I suspect that her publishing house would not question the golden goose) and she corrects them ad hoc, when questioned only it seems.

Comment: @user001 - Tolkien's changes were usually much bigger (enough to invoke a new copyright). The changes in different editions of HP have always been typos (e.g. last ancestor of Slytherin > last descendent of Slytherin)

Comment: @ibid She doesn't correct the manuscripts but has expanded on characters greatly in conversations

Comment: @user001 - Same as Tolkien and practically every other popular author.

Answer (score 8):

Yes (to some extent).

As part of an interview for her US book tour in October 2007, J.K. Rowling offered audiences some exclusive "*Harry Potter secrets*" during [Q & A sessions](https://bibliophilists.wordpress.com/2007/10/22/highlights-of-jk-rowlings-us-book-tour/). These 'facts' have been confirmed by several sources and are assumed to be correct.

> **Hermione greatly improved the life for house-elves after her
>   graduation**

Comment: Please note that at least one of these facts has been superseded by other interviews and Pottermore  *"Harry, Hermione and Ron all went back to school after the final battle to finish their education"* vs. "*Harry and Ron didn't go back. Hermione did."*

Comment: I only knew about the version where only Hermione went back. Which one is latest?

Comment: @Pwassonne - October 2007 vs November 2007 however the latter has been confirmed subsequently.